# Run MAVEN UI test on Azure devops deployment group

Tags: selenium, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I have an Azure pipeline that runs a Maven UI test on a deployment group on a local server, the issue is that the test runs a headless test, but we need to make it UI visual test. I have found some articles that help the self-hosted agent solve this issue as below
[Visible UI testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-microsoft-hosted-agents:%7E:text=Visible%20UI%20testing%20using%20self%2Dhosted%20Windows%20agents) but for the deployment group I could not find any related part.
how could I run a UI test for Maven (Not just selenium tests) on the azure Deployment group with Visible UI

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and concern, the reason why you could not run MAVEN UI test on Azure devops deployment group is that the agents in devops deployment group are run as service, and the agents run as service are not available for UI visual test.

Also, according to the document: [Visible UI testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-microsoft-hosted-agents:%7E:text=Visible%20UI%20testing%20using%20self%2Dhosted%20Windows%20agents) , you could also get to know it as mentioned below:

Agents that are configured to run as service can run Selenium tests only with headless browsers. If you are not using a headless browser, or if you are running UI tests for desktop apps, Windows agents must be configured to run as an **interactive process** with auto-logon enabled.